# Blockchain truffle Migration Error

Tags: blockchain, truffle, consensys-truffle

truffle migrate
Using network 'development'.

```
Running migration: 1_initial_migration.js   Deploying Migrations...
Error encountered, bailing. Network state unknown. Review successful
transactions manually. Error: Migrations contract constructor expected
1 arguments, received 0
    at /usr/local/lib/node_modules/truffle/build/webpack:/~/truffle-contract/contract.js:390:1
```

My Solidity File(Migration.sol)

```
pragma solidity ^0.4.17;

contract Migrations {
  address public owner;
  uint public last_completed_migration;

  modifier restricted() {
    if (msg.sender == owner) _;
  }

  constructor(Migrations) public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }

  function setCompleted(uint completed) public restricted {
    last_completed_migration = completed;
  }

  function upgrade(address new_address) public restricted {
    Migrations upgraded = Migrations(new_address);
    upgraded.setCompleted(last_completed_migration);
  }
}
```

My Migration file 
1_initial_migration.js

```
var Migrations = artifacts.require("./Migrations.sol");

module.exports = function(deployer) {
  deployer.deploy(Migrations);
};
```

truffle version
Truffle v4.1.11 (core: 4.1.11)
Solidity v0.4.24 (solc-js)

Answer (score 2):

Remove the constructor function parameter "Migrations", which is not used anywhere. It is working when I remove the "Migrations" argument. Use as below:

```
constructor() public {
    owner = msg.sender;
  }
```

Answer (score -1):

If on Ganache change to Instabul or change the CHAIN you are on